# Rudin Exercise 3.14 part (c) Confirmation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

If $\{s_n\}$ is a complex sequence, define its arithmetic means $\sigma_n$ by $$\sigma_n = \frac{s_0 + s_1 + \cdots + s_n}{n+1}.$$

Can it happen that $s_n > 0$ for all $n$ and that $\limsup s_n = \infty$, although $\lim\sigma_n = 0$?

Attempt:

Consider $s_n =
\begin{cases}
  1,  & n = 0 \\
  m,  & n = 3^m \\
  \frac{1}{3^n},  & else
\end{cases}$

Clearly $\lim\sup s_n = \infty$, since the subsequence $s_{3^m}$ diverges. My problem is showing $\lim\sigma_n = 0$.

$\sigma_n < \frac{s_0 + ... + s_n}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{s_k}{n}$

Since I want to show that $\lim \sigma_n = 0$, I should squeeze it and show that $\lim \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{s_k}{n} = 0$.

This limit is a product, so $\lim \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{s_k}{n} = 0 = \lim \frac{1}{n} * \lim \sum_{k=0}^n s_k = 0 * \lim \sum_{k=0}^n s_k$. Showing that the latter limit is finite will finish the proof. This looks to be the limit of a partial sum, so I really need to show that

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s_n$ converges. This converges if and only if $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^k*s_{2^k}$ converges. But (2, 3) = 1, so $(2^n, 3^n)$ have no terms in common. Therefore,

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^k*s_{2^k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{3})^k$ which converges.

Comment: The Cauchy condensation test can only be used when the sequence $(s_n)$ is non-increasing, which it isn't in your example. Even worse, the sum over all $s_k$ diverges because every $3^m$-th term is m, so you can't split off the $\frac{1}{n}$ term like that.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sigma_n \le \frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum_{k; \; 3^{k} \le n} k + \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac1{3^k}\right) \le \frac{(\ln n)^2}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^k} \underset{n\to \infty}\to 0$$

Comment: This is great, thank you. My only confusion is the limit of $\frac{(ln n)^2}{n+1}$. This is 0 by L'Hopital's, but is it possible to not use L'Hopital's? It was not covered in Rudin yet, since this is the chapter on limits and not derivatives.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(\ln n)^2}{n} =_{u:=\ln n} \lim\limits_{u\to \infty} u^2 e^{-u}\to 0$. Is this clear now?

Comment: Yes, but I need to work this from the theorems I have up to this point, and L'Hopital's Rule is covered in a later chapter, so I can't use it.

Comment: What are theorems that you have covered up to now?

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem, the definition using neighborhoods and the Cauchy criterion, and some special sequences including $\frac{1}{n^p}$ for p > 0 and $x^n$ for |x| < 1. We also have the definition of e as an infinite sum.

Comment: You don't need the Hopital to show the limit. You have the definition of $e^x$ or just $e$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138279/discussion-between-alex-and-youem).